Why is my NVMe SSD constantly at 100% on Windows 10?
I have a fairly new laptop (specs below) I got in March of this year. It is running Windows 10.  I don't have much installed.
It is constantly lagging and slow to respond. The processor nor the memory look like they are being 'taxed'. It appears to be related to SSD usage. There is only an SSD installed. The disk is constantly reporting 100% active in the Task Manager, even though CPU usage is low along with low memory usage. Even the actual read/write on the disk appears low (see attached screenshots).
I have been Googling solutions for the past two days and have tried most of the recommended solutions, disabling services, disabling scheduled tasks, even disabling the page file. Nothing resolves the issue.
Every time I think it's solved, the drive will eventually run up to 100% at some point. It makes the laptop pretty unusable during these periods.


Laptop Specs

Manufacturer: MSI
Model: Prestige 16 AI Evo
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H 3.80 GHz
Memory: 32.0 GB
GPU: Intel Arc Graphics
System Drive: NVMe WD PC SN560


Check your antivirus and protection software - is there more than one installed?  Are all of them running?

@cup Only antivirus is Microsoft Defender.

The issue can be fixed by disabling MSI mode for your Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI) used by StorACHI.sys driver. Here are the complete steps:

In the Device Manager window, expand IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers and right click on Standard SATA AHCI Controller, select Properties.

In the property sheet, switch to Driver tab and click Driver Details.If the Driver File Details window shows storahci.sys driver listed there, it means you’re running inbox driver and hence it is possible to disable MSI mode. Click OK.

Back on the property sheet, switch to Details tab. Against Property, select Device instance path from drop-down and note down the Value mentioned there.

Open Registry editor and navigate to following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI<AHCI Controller Value>\Device Parameters\Interrupt Management\MessageSignaledInterruptProperties

In the right pane of MessageSignaledInterruptProperties key, look for the registry DWORD (REG_DWORD) named MSISupported which should be corresponding to Value 1 as its Data. Double click on the DWORD to modify its value:

Finally, set the Value data as 0 and click OK. Close Registry Editor and reboot. After restarting your machine, the 100% disk usage problem should disappear.


P.S. If the above method doesn’t works, you can try disabling Superfetch in Windows 10. This has been helped a few users to get rid of this problem.

Thank you for the help.  I do not have an IDE ATA/ATAPI controller in my Device Manager.  I have Disk drives with one item "NVMe WD PC SN560 SDDPNQE-1T00-1032".
In my registry, which  would be the correct one.  I have 25 items under the PCI entry.
I don't have Superfetch running.  I went looking for that a while back.

Your issue isn't new happens to a lot of people. And in your case nvme you're using you need to take it out of your laptop and throw it into trash. Cheap nvmes without dram will always cause freezing issues.
If you can afford get yourself nvme with dram such as kc3000 the bigger drive you buy the more dram it will have. If you can afford get yourself 1tb kc3000 and you will never again experience freezing issues.
Also never fill it over 80%
Second option is to keep using drive you currently have. The only option to make it work again is to delete it creating unallocated space then create new volume and install windows on it again. Freezing will go away but it will comeback.
Also get yourself tool called dism++ as you could use it to make backup.wim of your system. Then delete format your drive and restore system apps and settings to what you had before you formatted it without the need for setting and installing everything again.
Once again never again buy any nvme drive without dram even if you want to use it only for storage.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
